# Rails - Change locations of the default views, layouts, and partials paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I want to change the location of my view files from `app/views/*` to `view/html/*`, my layouts directory from `app/views/layouts/*` to `view/layouts/*`, and, lastly, I would like to store my partials separate from my views in a location like `view/partials/*`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd be very curious as to *why* you'd want to do this.

Rails does have [view paths](http://www.axehomeyg.com/2009/06/10/view-path-manipulation-for-rails-with-aop/) but these aren't really capable of this kind of customization.

You'd be better off using symlinks on a *nix like OS.

```
$ ln -s source_file link_name
```

For example:

```
$ ln -s app/views view/html
```

Comment: Good question, not sure about Heroku.